# get multiple substrings from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have

```
tmp_body_symbols="things <st>hello</st> and <st>blue</st> by <st>orange</st>"
str1_markerstring = "<st>"
str2_markerstring = "</st>"
frags << tmp_body_symbols[/#{str1_markerstring}(.*?)#{str2_markerstring}/m, 1]
```

frags is "hello" but I want ["hello","blue","orange"]

How woudl I do that?

Comment: Isn't an `XML` parser recommended for such a problem?

Comment: yeah, was thinking about using nokogiri but this is all that we're really capturing and seems like overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scan`:

```
tmp_body_symbols.scan(/#{str1_markerstring}(.*?)#{str2_markerstring}/m).flatten
```

See also: [Ruby docs for `String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

Comment: thx Doorknob, I updated the question from using different variable names but you got it right anyway

Comment: Do you need the multiline modifier (`/m`)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland If the tags can potentially contain multiline data (ex. `<st>foo\nbar\nbaz</st>`), then yes. I've just kept the regex the same as in the original question, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/)** to parse HTML/XML

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri' 

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse("things <st>hello</st> and <st>blue</st> by <st>orange</st>")
doc.css('st').map(&:text)
#=> ["hello", "blue", "orange"]
```

More Info : http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html

Comment: thx, makes sense, might do this down the road but more quick and dirty for this one off

Comment: It was just one line but when you need to get data from whole page/file I think this is better to use.

Comment: i agree - when it gets there; nokogiri would probably be a great soln

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a capture group, as @Doorknob has done, or without a capture group, by using a ("zero-width") positive look-behind and positive-lookahead:

```
tmp = "things <st>hello</st> and <st>blue</st> by <st>orange</st>"
s1 = "<st>"
s2 = "</st>"

tmp.scan(/(?<=#{ s1 }).*?(?=#{ s2 })/).flatten
  #=> ["hello", "blue", "orange"]
```

- `(?<=#{ s1 })`, which evaluates to `(?<=<st>)`, is the positive look-behind.
- `(?=#{ s2 })`, which evaluates to `(?=</st>)`, is the positive look-behind.
- `?` following `.*` makes it "non-greedy". Without it:

```
tmp.scan(/(?<=#{ s1 }).*(?=#{ s2 })/).flatten
  #=> ["hello</st> and <st>blue</st> by <st>orange"]
```